# prevent click on div to underlying <a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i want to prevent the click on a overlay button (div) that is on top of an href that is inside an ng-repeat, this is the neg repeat with the favorite-delete button on top of the

```
<div style="margin-top:110px;" id="favoritecdlist" ng-controller="UserController">
     <div class="cdscrollcontainer" ng-repeat="cd in favoriteCds">
            <a href="~/cd/{{cd.id_cd}}" class="cdscrollcell" id="{{cd.id_program}}">
              <div class="favorite-delete" ng-click="RemoveCDFromFavoriteList(cd.id_cd)">x</div>
                 <img class="cdimage" ng-src="{{cd.url}}">
                 <div class="cdimagebackground">
                 <div class="cdtitle">{{cd.cdName}} ({{cd.ReleaseYear}})</div>
              </div>
            </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller section for the removal of the favorite from the list, i first make a fade-out (1sec) then fire the actual web service to remove it from the database.

```
$scope.RemoveCDFromFavoriteList = function (id_cd) {
        $('#' + id_cd + '').css("opacity", "0").css("transition-duration", "1s");

            $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: "/User/RemoveUserFavoriteCD?id_cd=" + id_cd,
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $('#' + id_cd + '').css('display', 'none');
                }).error(function (data) {
                    $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
                });
}
```

the problem is that when i click on the favorite-delete i actually removes the image from the list, it removes it from the database but directly after is loads the page with the details of the CD. how do i prevent this from happening, i tried with the stoppropagation and preventdefault but can't seem to get it working, as well as the use of a directive, could not get it to work. What do i need to do to get it to work?

I tried the add the following to userController.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('favorite-delete').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    })
```

but also with no luck the Href link still loads and i need both

Comment: In the ng-click directive of the element that you would like to remain clickable, add $event.stopPropagation();

`ng-click="RemoveCDFromFavoriteList(cd.id_cd); $event.stopPropagation();"`

Out of curiosity, if you don't want the anchor element to do anything, why is it there?

You'll also need to revisit your $http resolution if you upgrade Angular. Angular 1.6 had some breaking changes and no longer has a .success() method to resolve the promise. You must now use .then() like a normal Promise

Comment: hi, i tried the "$event.stop..." within the ng-click but it does not work, the page still get loaded. What do you mean with the anchor element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok in order to get it to work i had to add the $event.stopPropagation(); and the $event.preventDefault() in the ng-click so it became finally as this, thanks @WrkOnMyMachine for the help and me getting in the right direction (oh and completely ignore the $(document).ready......) this is the working version.

```
<div style="margin-top:110px;" id="favoritecdlist" ng-controller="UserController">
 <div class="cdscrollcontainer" ng-repeat="cd in favoriteCds">
        <a href="~/cd/{{cd.id_cd}}" class="cdscrollcell" id="{{cd.id_program}}">
          <div class="favorite-delete" ng-click="RemoveCDFromFavoriteList(cd.id_cd); $event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault()">x</div>
             <img class="cdimage" ng-src="{{cd.url}}">
             <div class="cdimagebackground">
             <div class="cdtitle">{{cd.cdName}} ({{cd.ReleaseYear}})</div>
          </div>
        </a>
 </div>
```